# Fuzzy identity fingerprinting

Tags: uniqueidentifier, fingerprint, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I have a spreadsheet with values like address, name, IBAN, e-mail and want to identify when a customer last time bought something.

The problem is: some fields contain spelling mistakes, others were deliberately entered wrong.

On GitHub, several libraries like https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy, https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match or https://github.com/atom/fuzzaldrin are available to perform fuzzy searches based on a single and comparable column. But I want to combine multiple fields - this sounds like a common problem and I expected to find existing solutions out there.

Can you recommend approaches for such a problem? Are there existing projects for such a problem which I am missing?
Is a regular string-distance over all the fields usually good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned it in your other question, but the [dedupe python library](https://github.com/datamade/dedupe) [does what you want](http://dedupe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Matching-records.html#record-by-record-or-field-by-field).

Basically, it calculates the distance between each field in a pair of rows, then learns optimal weights to combine those distances into a single record-pair score.

Answer (score 0):

So far I believe http://blog.yhat.com/posts/fuzzy-matching-with-yhat.html and using fuzzyWuzzy seems to be the best approach.